# imprimir mi resultado de mi query select en PHP

Tags: php

hola amigos estoy atorado con el siguiente problema uso Sqlserver 2014
tengo un select donde me arroja este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi problema es en php quiero mostrar el mismo resultado pero no obtengo nada..
mi script php:

```
<?php
$server = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; //tapo mi ip para evitar problema
$connectionInfo2 = array( "Database"=>"mibaseprivada", "UID"=>"mixael", "PWD"=>"1234");
$conn2 = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo2);
if( $conn2 ) {
  echo "Conexion realizada :D <br />";
}else{
   echo "Error al conectar Base2 :C<br />";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//query de sqlserver
$queryFechaDeVencimiento=" select (Case when (select T1.U_FechaEmision from OCRD T1 WHERE T1.cardcode='C00199')='S' then DATEADD(DAY,30,cast('2019-11-18' as date)) else DATEADD(DAY,30,cast('2019-12-30' as date)) end) as valor";

$resultado4=sqlsrv_query($conn2,$queryFechaDeVencimiento);

while($filas=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado4)){
echo "RESULTADO DEL QUERY:<br>";
echo $filas['valor'];
}

?>
```

en mi navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($filas);` dentro del `while` para ver lo que hay. Puede que `sqlsrv_fetch_array` no te esté devolviendo un array asociativo. En ese caso debes ponerlo así: `while($filas=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado4, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){` o usar otro estilo ...

Comment: hola gracias por responder hize cambios y probe y sigo sin obtener el resultado ,pero al usar el var_dump(filas) obtengo mi informacion:

array(1) { ["valor"]=> object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-12-18 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "America/Tegucigalpa" } } 
como puedo recuperar "2019-12-18"

Comment: Revisa que la consulta REALMENTE devuelve algo y como dice el amigo del anterior comentario haz un var_dump($filas) para ver que resultados alberga $filas. No obstante la documentacion sobre este metodo dice que tienes que usar una constante `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` en `sqlsrv_fetch_array` quedando como sigue `sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado4, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )`

Answer (score 1):

El `var_dump` muestra que `sqlsrv` devuelve directamente un objeto `DateTime` en aquellas columnas que son del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` en la base de datos, tal y como se afirma en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-datetime-objects-using-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15).

Entonces para obtener el dato puedes aplicar `format` sobre el resultado. Se trata de uno de los métodos aplicables a los objetos `DateTime` en PHP.

Por ejemplo:

```
while($filas=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado4,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "RESULTADO DEL QUERY:<br>";
    $mDate=$filas['valor'];
    echo $mDate->format("Y-m-d");
}
```

Nótese que se ha indicado un `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`como fetch style, de lo contrario te devolverá datos como array asociativo y numérico, recargando la memoria.