# date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given in "Ruta"

Tags: php, sql-server, datatables

estoy haciendo una consulta SQLServer usando PHP para mostrarla en DataTables, pero hay un campo en la DB que está como datetime, estoy tratando de mostrarla con esto:

```
<td>'.date_format($datos['Fecha_Retiro'],'Y m d H:i:s').'</td>
```

Es la primera vez que uso SQLServer con php en un proyecto, así que imagino que la función no es correcta porque he intentado de varias maneras como siempre lo he hecho con MySQL pero siempre recibo un error similar... Con ese fragmento de código descrito estoy recibiendo este error en la tabla/columna que quiero mostrar como por ejemplo:

2000-01-01 00:00:00

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given in (rutadel/archivo/con_linea_error.php"
```

No puedo cambiar el datetime por date, porque estas tablas hacen parte de otro programa que usa toda la oficina y no fue creado por mi como para poder modificar el código en lo que pueda afectar esa columna, fue creado por una empresa aparte como una solución antes de yo llegar a este nuevo empleo :/

Muchas Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por qué no haces un `convert` del campo en el query `sql`?

Comment: Mmm, tendría que crear otro select aparte? no entiendo 

Comment: Necesitas usar date() y convertir a timestamp con strtotime: `date('Y m d H:i:s', strtotime($datos['Fecha_Retiro'])).`

Comment: Entiendo... bueno parece que si solucionó el problema eso, sin embargo ahora tengo otro... pensé en agregarlo a la pregunta pero creo que es mejor crear una aparte.. Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Si la columna es del tipo `DateTime` en la tabla, la API de Sql Server para PHP te da los resultados como un objeto `DateTime` (de PHP)  y puedes pasar a usarlo directamente. Me parece que hay ya alguna respuesta que trata este tema, ahora reviso y te digo.

Comment: Efectivamente, [revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/319445/29967). SQL Server te devuelve un objeto `DateTime` (no tienes que crearlo como se suele hacer en MySQL por ejemplo), sino solamente aplicar `format` sobre el valor que obtendrías en `$datos['Fecha_Retiro']`, de todos modos, puedes verificarlo con `var_dump($datos['Fecha_Retiro']);` casi seguro que será un objeto `DateTime` a no ser que la columna sea de otro tipo o el campo esté vacío.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Solucionado con sus respuestas! 